# Programs that want to be packaged with exe4j use javaw to run

Tags: exe4j

How to set exe4j to use javaW to execute the program?
I tried to use the GUI Application and still use java to run the program, which will cause my program to not execute normally.If you try to rename javaw to java, you will get an environment error.

Answer (score 0):

exe4j creates launchers that use JNI to create the JVM. They do no call java or javaw. An exe4j launcher in console mode behaves similarly to java and an exe4j launcher in GUI mode behaves similarly to javaw.

Comment: If I call the jvm directly, why is the java environment error prompted after I delete java.exe?

Comment: Or do you know of any packaged software that can call javaw to execute a program?